# Is it possible to do this in Microsoft word?

Tags: ms-word

I have a list of values like "fee" "fi" "fo" "fum". I would like to have a popup window where I can check each of the values I want to see in the current document (say "fee" and "fi") and have them appear thus:

fee, fi

If I select "fee" "fo" and "fum" I would like to have them appear thus:

fee, fo, fum

Is there any way to do this in Microsoft Word? Building Blocks is nice but doesn't seem to offer more advanced features like this...

Comment: Do you know anything about vba?

Comment: No but I would like to learn...

Comment: Well, here is a [getting started page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff604039%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and for your popup window you should look up how to use 'user forms'.

Comment: is there a less programming intensive way to do this?

Comment: I don't think so. But you're asking on the wrong website if you need a 'less programming intense' way.

Comment: not necessarily. Theres nothing wrong with seeking out efficiency. if something can be done easily using the GUI, why jump straight to coding?

Comment: Look at the [stackoverflow's help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Stackoverflow is not for asking about efficiency in the gui of programs like ms-word. I wouldn't categorize it as a 'software-tool commonly used by programmers'. There are other forums for that.